# Расширяющаяся форма в qt

Tags: android, c++, qt, qtcreator

Создаю обычный проект qt widgets с формой. Добавляю на форму layout, на него кидаю банальный textedit и button через дизайнер, ставлю в sizepolicy везде expanding. Собираю всё это, но потом почему-то слой не растягивается при изменении размеров окна готового приложения. Что я делаю не так? Интересует именно через дизайнер, поскольку если руками писать, то всё работает так как я и хочу. Спасибо

Comment: Правой кнопкой по MainWindow (в инспекторе объектов, справа вверху, где иерархия объектов виджета) -> компоновка -> скомпоновать по сетке (горизонтально/вертикально - как вам нужно)

Comment: Правильно понимаю, что используя вертикальный layout можно добиться только вертикального растяжения?

Comment: Странно, на win растягивается в таком случае, деплою на андроид, всё также не растягиватеся

Comment: С `Android` не сталкивался. Добавьте метку Android в вопрос, кто-нибудь ответит

Comment: Что-то я снова запутался. Скомпоновал по сетке. Форму растягивается только вертикально. Горизонтально я могу её только  сжать сначала. а потом растянуть до предыдущего размера, но не больше

Comment: может у вас максимальный размер по ширине указан такой ?

Comment: Максимум вроде нигде не указан, поставил Expanding на всё, потом попробовал Preferred

Comment: Если кого не затруднит, то вот https://github.com/Jihadist/LeetGUITranslator проект

Comment: [Вот](https://github.com/Jihadist/LeetGUITranslator/blob/577d6edc07cbb4e5375e74559b17a540cc069e0f/mainwindow.ui#L32) оно ваше свойство maximumSize, в QtDesigner его найдите и поставьте сколько вам нужно

Comment: Спасибо, муху в глазу и не заметил